# How to follow a redirect in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that has a conditional context menu. The menu should only appear if you right click on a link with "youtube.com" as the hostname.

It works most of the time, except for when using social media like facebook or twitter. Facebook and twitter redirect internally, causing my code to not recognize the URL, and thus not display the context menu.
Here is what my code looks like:

```
var contexts = ["selection","frame","page","editable", "link", "video"];
var acceptedURLs = ["*://*.youtube.com/*", "*://youtube.com/*","*://*.soundcloud.com/*","*://soundcloud.com/*"];
var title = "Add to queue";
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts": contexts, "documentUrlPatterns": acceptedURLs});
```

Is there any way to figure out whether a URL will redirect from within a chrome extension?

Comment: Not without fetching the contents of the URL to see if it gives you a 3xx status.  Or knowing exactly what sites like Facebook and Twitter use as the format of a redirect URL.

Comment: `webRequest` or `webNavigation` API might do the job, but I don't immediately see how to hook it up with context menus.